# TreeMap keys does not display in ascending order

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I am using Treemap to get key value pair in ascending order.

I have key value pair as

```
key  |  Value

 2      Rooney 
 7      Ronaldo
 20     Persie
 1      Pele
 10     Ramires
```

> I have used Map.Entry and also advanced for loop to iterate key value.

Problem is that the output is not in proper ascending order as i want.

```
Output 

key  |  Value

 1      Pele
 10     Ramires     
 2      Rooney
 20     Persie 
 7      Ronaldo
```

> Actual output as I want to display is shown below.

```
Output 

    key  |  Value

     1      Pele          
     2      Rooney
     7      Ronaldo
     10     Ramires
     20     Persie
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: If your keys are Strings, they'll be sorted by lexicographical order, instead of the numeric order you are expecting.

Comment: does Key is of type String

Comment: Code sample? Hard to tell you the fix without seeing the code that needs fixing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change key to int. If you use string, the map will be sorted in the lexicographical order.